# Using Beautiful Soup To Extract Website Data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from the Pine Script Reference Manual into a json file using Beautiful Soup, but everytime I try, it saves the json file but with nothing inside of it.This prevents me from using the json file in another code.

This is the code I am using:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json 

url = "https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")


# extract the desired data from the soup object
def extract_data(soup):
    data = {}
    for item in soup.find_all("div", class_="tv-pine-reference-item"):
        h3 = item.find("h3")
        if h3:
            topic = h3.text

            text = item.find("div", class_="tv-pine-reference-item__text.tv-text")
            definition = text.text if text else None

            syntax = item.find("pre", class_="tv-pine-reference-item__syntax")
            example = syntax.text if syntax else None

            data[topic] = {"definition": definition, "example": example}
    return data


data = extract_data(soup)

# save the data in json format to the desired directory
with open("PineScriptv5Manual.json", "w") as f: 
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: the page is loaded with JavaScript - you ight notice if you [print the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ND2.png) in `soup` or [preview the source html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOZGh.png) in the [network logs](https://support.happyfox.com/kb/article/882-accessing-the-browser-console-and-network-logs/). You'll have to either find an API for fetching the data you want or try [using selenium](https://pastebin.com/VLZ2vPYK) [or anything else that supports JavaScript]. Also, I think the `class_` argument for `text` has a `.` where there should be space

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the recommendation by @Driftr95, your code can be quickly fixed by changing the web scraping approach from `request.get()` to a more dynamic approach offered by a library like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

After installing the library with pip through the following:

```
pip install selenium
```

And then installing the appropriate web driver executable for your browser of choice (e.g., [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)), we can add a few lines of code to your script to allow the page to dynamically load the page prior to your BeautifulSoup parsing.

Note: Just make sure when downloading your ChromeDriver tool to have it match your browser's version by checking the `About Chrome` Settings page (i.e., open Chrome to `chrome://settings/help`)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver # pip install selenium

# Make sure to modify the path to your chromedriver executable
# The driver can be downloaded from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = './chrome_driver/chromedriver'
# Destination URL to Parse
URL = "https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(5) # Provide the site some time to dynamically load the content via JS
html = driver.page_source # Pull the website text upon loading

# The rest of your code as posted, with exported data to the output JSON file
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


# extract the desired data from the soup object
def extract_data(soup):
    data = {}
    for item in soup.find_all("div", class_="tv-pine-reference-item"):
        h3 = item.find("h3")
        if h3:
            topic = h3.text

            text = item.find("div", class_="tv-pine-reference-item__text.tv-text")
            definition = text.text if text else None

            syntax = item.find("pre", class_="tv-pine-reference-item__syntax")
            example = syntax.text if syntax else None

            data[topic] = {"definition": definition, "example": example}
    return data


data = extract_data(soup)

# save the data in json format to the desired directory
with open("PineScriptv5Manual.json", "w") as f: 
    json.dump(data, f, indent=6)
```